# IOS 13 UIWindow instance is nil during application launching

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, ios13, uiwindow

I am trying to passing my `managedObjectContext` to the next controller.
I innate a `UIWindow` instance in my appDelegate file, as I need to obtain my stand by controller.
However, Xcode said my `UIWindow` instance is nil.

This id my code:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    if let tabViewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {
        let navController = tabViewControllers[0]  as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navController.viewControllers.first as! CurrentLocationViewController
        controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    }

    return true
}
```

[image: Debug]

[image]
[image]

It is a bit strange. How to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line ????

Comment: let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

Comment: Is this iOS 13?

Comment: yeah it is in iOS 13

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> IOS 13 window is inside SceneDelegate while prior to 13 is inside AppDelegate

Move code inside `SceneDelegate`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    if let tabViewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {
       let navController = tabViewControllers[0]  as! UINavigationController
       let controller = navController.viewControllers.first as! CurrentLocationViewController
       controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
     }
}
```

Comment: It works now. Just trying to figure out why not in the func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}.                 I have read the document regarding the method you mention, the second method is for non-scene configuration purpose.  So, I should put the data configuration file in second method. Am I right?

Comment: For example, in future, If I need an singleton instance for my app, such as a GPS locator, I should put in the the func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions). right?

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` still be called even before `willConnectTo`  you can add any configuration inside it

Answer (score 7):

## Another Possible Solution

1. Declare `var window: UIWindow?` in your `AppDelegate.swift`.
2. Remove `SceneDelegate.swift` from your files.
3. Remove `Application Scene Manifest` from `Info.plist`.
4. Use `window` object in your `AppDelegate.swift` as you want.